# GWT handle print event of the browser window

Tags: javascript, gwt

I need to handle the event when the user clicks on "Print" button or issues a Ctrl+P. The reason is that we added a print method to our GWT application which prepares a nice printout. This cannot be done with CSS. Therefore we need to capture the event.  I already found this here https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/ but I am not sure of how to implement that in GWT? Any help appreciated.

I use GWT 2.8.

Best regards
Hannes

Comment: You can use the JSNI http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

Comment: or JsInterop. That would be the "new" way to do such things

Answer (score 0):

after all I solved it this way and I learned a lot about JSNI on this way :-)

```
public native void handlePrintEvent() /*-{

    var theInstance = this;
    (function() {
        var beforePrint = function() {
            console.log('Functionality to run before printing.');
            theInstance.@com.myproject.xyz::preparePrint()();
        };
        var afterPrint = function() {
            console.log('Functionality to run after printing');

        };

        if (window.matchMedia) {
            var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
            mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
                if (mql.matches) {
                    beforePrint();
                } else {
                    afterPrint();
                }
            });
        }

        window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
        window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
    }());
}-*/;
```

Very important the thing with the variable theInstance, otherwise it won't work!

This function should be called in the C'tor of your Widget (com.myproject.xyz) class to install the print handlers

Then you need to implement the function preparePrint() to execute some print specific logic (which was actually what I needed).

Hope someone else finds this useful